# Where does this expression for a Brachistochrone come from?

Tags: calculus, curves, cycloid

I came across this expression in Thomas' Calculus: early transcendentals. I understood the expressions describing the Brachistochrone curve up until this point where the derivation jumps from:

$\frac{ds}{dT}=\sqrt{2gy}$

Where T is time, ds is arc length differential and g is acceleration due to gravity to:

$dT=\frac{ds}{\sqrt{2gy}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+(dy/dx)^2}dx}{\sqrt{2gy}}$

The 2nd part of this is what confuses me as to how $ds$ becomes $\sqrt{1+(dy/dx)^2}dx$ in a single trivial step as I cannot think of a simple conversion from one to the other and neither is it explicitly described in the book.

Comment: Informally ... $ds$ is "infinitesimal change in arc-length", which is given by $\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$. With a bit of differential sleight-of-hand, we can "factor-out" a $dx$: $$\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}=\sqrt{\left(1+\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}\right)dx^2}=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\;dx$$

Comment: @Blue I often see references to these sorts of manipulations as "informal"; what *would* be formal?

Comment: @FShrike  I think because $ds=\sqrt{(dx^2)+(dy^2)}$ is in reality just an informal abbreviation of $ds=\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2}$; at least that is what my textbook claims...